# How to setup reminders in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Is there a way to setup reminders in windows 8 ? 
I am not looking to do this in a mail client or using third party software. 
 I have tried to do this using the task scheduler, but displaying just a message is deprecated.

Comment: If you're using Windows 8.1 with the latest update, you should be able to use the [Alarm](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/alarms-app-faq) app which comes bundled with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link, it might help:

http://www.howtogeek.com/136894/how-to-create-popup-reminders-with-no-additional-software/

and this:

http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/96547-create-popup-reminder-using-batch-file.html

hope this helps